# Open multiple CSVs in a background workbook, sort by date and import specific column to active workbook

Tags: vba, excel, loops, csv

I have a macro-enabled Workbook (MRMTool_V6) that in the first row has names of assets. In column A I have dates, sorted from the newest to the oldest.

[image: MRMTool_V6]

I need some help to figure out how to open a new Workbook - TempFile, that will be looping trough the items in row 1 of MRMTool_V6 ,import a .CSV file to TempFile, sort that data by date, copy the "Close" column from the TempFile and paste it to the main file - MRMTool_V6. Than clear the contents and connections of the TempFile and repeat the same with the next asset.

I need this for every asset in row 1, preferably done in the background, without displaying the processes taking place in the TempFile.

I need this, because the length of the data is inconsistent. I have different amount of close prices for most assets. When all data for all assets is imported to a single file, it needs to be sorted by date - from latest to oldest. When that is done, "holes in the data appear.

I managed to create a file that imports all close prices before.

[image: Data before sorting]

When sorted by date, this is the result.

[image: data after sorting]

This is the loop that I am using in this file"

```
Dim CPDB As Worksheet
Dim FSO As Object
Dim Folder As Object
Dim CurrFile As Object
Dim i As Variant

Set CPDB = Sheets("Close Prices Database")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = FSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\Betty\AppData\Roaming\MetaQuotes\Terminal\" & _
                                "B4D9BCD10BE9B5248AFCB2BE2411BA10\MQL4\Files")
Set CurrFile = Folder.Files

'   IMPORT HISTORICAL DATA FROM .CSV TO SHEET 'CPDB' FOR ALL ITEMS

    For Each CurrFile In Folder.Files
        i = CPDB.Cells(3, CPDB.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If CPDB.Cells(2, 2) <> "" Then
            With CPDB.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & CurrFile, _
                                        Destination:=CPDB.Cells(3, i + 1))
                .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
                .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = True
                .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 1, 9, 9, 9, 9)
                .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
                i = i + 1
            End With
        End If
    Next
```

You can find the whole code for this old file here:

https://pastebin.com/CwuJKJUb

To avoid this I need to open each asset's .CSV separately, sort it by date and import the close prices to the main file.

All pointers and directions are much appreciated.

Comment: "without displaying" Put `application.screenupdating = false ` at the top of your code. Don't forget to turn it back to true at the bottom.

Comment: Because you gave out wayyyyy too much information in your question. You need to keep it simple and follow [mcve]

Comment: @QHarr, any ideas?

Comment: Personally I don't think I've ever grabbed someone's provided data, I always make a small mockup on my own machine and test it that way. Mileage may vary, but personally I rarely use *exactly* what is provided. And technically they're still there in the edit history, so if someone was so inclined they could go find them

Comment: Fair enough, @ Marcucciboy2. Any ideas coming your way in regards of the question?

Comment: How about adding only the new data every day, so you can skip all the sorting, just find the matching date, and copy over that value?

Comment: @Luuklag, the assets in row 1 vary. And this tool is meant to calculate a lot of things, so it needs to be ran a few times a day in order to be effective.

Comment: I thought you needed close prices, exchanges only close once a day....

Comment: Yes, but the assets traded vary in the different times of the day. Every time this Toll is going to be ran, some assets will be traded and some will not, which affects the exposure. I need this to calculate VaR at least 3 times a day for risk management purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just merging data from multiple CSV files into a single sheet in Excel?  I read your description and I can't tell what the sort has to do with anything.  If you need to sort, you can do it at the end, after everything has been merged together, right.

```
' Merge data from multime files into one sheet.
Sub R_AnalysisMerger()
    Dim WSA As Worksheet
    Dim bookList As Workbook
    Dim SelectedFiles() As Variant
    Dim NFile As Long
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim Ws As Worksheet, vDB As Variant, rngT As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False


    Set Ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Ws.UsedRange.Clear
    'change folder path of excel files here
    SelectedFiles = Application.GetOpenFilename(filefilter:="Excel Files (*.csv*), *.csv*", MultiSelect:=True)


    For NFile = LBound(SelectedFiles) To UBound(SelectedFiles)
        FileName = SelectedFiles(NFile)
        Set bookList = Workbooks.Open(FileName, Format:=2)
        Set WSA = bookList.Sheets(1)
        With WSA
            vDB = .UsedRange
            Set rngT = Ws.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)(2)
            If rngT.Row = 2 Then Set rngT = Ws.Range("a1")
            rngT.Resize(UBound(vDB, 1), UBound(vDB, 2)) = vDB

            bookList.Close (0)
        End With
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Ws.Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: @ruguy72, thank you for your answer! However, I will be able to test your code later today, or even tomorrow, as I am at work now. In order to make it a bit clearer, the length of each CSV of each instrument in row 1 is different. So when I sort them by date I get blank cells at the top, as the function is basically turning the array upside-down. For this purpose, I need to open each CSV in a separate workbook, sort the data by date and import column 6 from it to this worksheet.

Comment: As for the title of the question, it was edited by a SO member upon posting, and I didn't want to oppose him.